# Swift Http Client Doesn't Send Request

Tags: swift, httprequest

I have this function to test sending HTTP request.

```
public func test(url: URL) {
    print("test")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
        print("Entered the completionHandler")
        guard err == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            print(err!)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I run the code in my test just to make sure that it's sending request.
And it never gets into the completion block (`Entered the completionHandler` never got printed). I am new to Swift what do I miss?

```
func test_download() {
    myClient.test(url: URL(string:"https://www.google.com")!)
    print("sleeping...")
    sleep(10)
    print("done...")
}
```

Comment: Except for duplicated forced unwrapping, that code should be working. Are rest of the print calls working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not properly using the closure. Try this instead:

```
// No need to explicitly set GET method since this is the default one.
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
    print("Entered the completionHandler")
    guard err == nil else {
        print("error calling GET")
        return
    }
    // Do whatever you need to with data and response in here

}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to configured on your session using `URLSessionConfiguration`:-

```
let urlConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
urlConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
urlConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: urlConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
//Now try your code
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
        print("Entered the completionHandler")
        guard err == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            print(err!)
            return
        }
    }
task.resume()
```